# Add Rows together with the same date in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Im trying to add up values that have the same day of the week

My Query:

```
SELECT c.CounterID,
total(CASE WHEN strftime('%w', c.Date) = 1 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Monday,
total(CASE WHEN strftime('%w', c.Date) = 2 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Tuesday,
total(CASE WHEN strftime('%w', c.Date) = 3 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Wednesday,
total(CASE WHEN strftime('%w', c.Date) = 4 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Thursday,
total(CASE WHEN strftime('%w', c.Date) = 5 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Friday,
total(CASE WHEN strftime('%w', c.Date) = 6 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Saturday,
total(CASE WHEN strftime('%w', c.Date) = 0 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Sunday
FROM CounterItems c
GROUP BY c.CounterID
```

Above returns 0 for each Day of the week column. Why isn't it adding up the values?

EDIT: Below is my Table structure

```
ID|CounterID|Value|Date
```

EDIT2: This is the date format `2015-02-13 01:07:21`

Comment: Can you post an example of the Date format from your database? Is the Date in an acceptable format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to `CAST()` `strftime` function  to `Integer`. See below:

```
SELECT c.CounterID,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN CAST(strftime('%w', c.Date) AS INTEGER) = 1 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Monday,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN CAST(strftime('%w', c.Date) AS INTEGER) = 2 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Tuesday,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN CAST(strftime('%w', c.Date) AS INTEGER) = 3 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Wednesday,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN CAST(strftime('%w', c.Date) AS INTEGER) = 4 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Thursday,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN CAST(strftime('%w', c.Date) AS INTEGER) = 5 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Friday,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN CAST(strftime('%w', c.Date) AS INTEGER) = 6 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Saturday,
       TOTAL(CASE WHEN CAST(strftime('%w', c.Date) AS INTEGER) = 0 THEN c.Value ELSE 0 END) AS Sunday
FROM CounterItems c
GROUP BY c.CounterID
```

Comment: My date format is `2015-02-13 01:07:21` could that be why?

Comment: Still no luck any other ideas?

Comment: I think you need to cast the whole strftime method to integer. Try my another edit above.

Comment: That's great to have helped you!. :-)